# In Firefox 4, how do I change the download directory Firefox starts in when it "asks me every time"?

Tags: firefox, download

Here's my situation: I'm running Firefox 4 (Beta 12) in Red Hat Linux.  I have the following settings:

- "Ask me every time" where to download files; and
- Don't remember download history

I want to keep these. However, when I click a link to download, and FF brings up the "Enter name of file to save to" dialog, that dialog defaults to `~/Downloads`. I want to change that default to another directory.  How can I do this?

Please note that I am **not** asking how to change FF's settings to automatically save all files to a particular directory.  I still want FF to ask me where to save files, I just want to change the directory that the dialog defaults to.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In `about:config`, change the `browser.download.lastDir` setting.
2. Add this line to the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/user-dirs.dirs` file:

   ```
   XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/whatever"
   ```

   (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defaults to `~/.config`)